# Subtraction using DateTime retrieved from database giving strange results

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, unity-game-engine, utc

I am having some trouble doing some DateTime subtractions with a time that I have received from a MySQL database. All of the non-UTC times are in the American format.

This is the time I have received (I retrieve it from the database using a Ruby on Rails app), which comes in the form of a string:

```
2017-04-10T15:00:00.000Z
```

I then parse the string to convert it to a DateTime and do a debug of the regular DateTime (without the offset):

```
start_time = DateTimeOffset.Parse(event_time[2]);
Debug.Log(start_time.DateTime);
```

Which then shows the following:

```
4/10/2017 3:00:00 PM
```

This appears similar to the format I usually use (i.e. M/dd/yyy h/mm/ss tt), so I do a quick comparison with the current time to check exactly how far off I am from it (for reference, DateTime.Now = 4/10/2017 12:46:26 AM when I ran this code last):

```
TimeSpan tmp;
tmp = (start_time.DateTime).Subtract(DateTime.Now);

Debug.Log(tmp)
```

However, this gives me the following result:

```
-736428.00:46:22.2744445
```

Doing such an operation with the following gives me a normal result:

```
DateTime tmp2;
TimeSpan tmp3;

tmp2 = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 360));

tmp3 = tmp2.Subtract(DateTime.Now)

Debug.Log(tmp2);
Debug.Log(tmp3);
```

Normal Result:

```
4/10/2017 12:52:26 AM
00:06:00
```

Is there something wrong with how I have handled the time I got from my database? I can not seem to get a normal result no matter what I try.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I could not reproduce your issue.  I got:

"14:13:34"

http://prntscr.com/eujzg1

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue with 2017-04-10T15:00:00.000Z as the start_date so something else is in play. Are there any NULLs in the database for this field ? 
The result of -736428.00:46:22.2744445 means 736428 days 46 minues and 22.27 seconds... or more precisely the difference between 01/01/0001 12:00 AM and DateTime.Now when you ran the code (4/10/2017 12:46 AM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue (kind of?).

I also must apologize since I did not fully describe how I was using the code that I originally posted.

It turns out the issue was that I was that I was attempting to perform the DateTime subtraction in another script (I am doing this all within Unity, like I mentioned earlier).

For example, this was the code giving me the erroneous output in the script Buttonscript.cs:

```
TimeSpan tmpButtonController;
tmpButtonController = HighscoreController.GetComponent<HSController>().start_time.DateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
Debug.Log(tmpButtonController);
```

But if I do the same thing, but inside the same script in which I parse the string (HSController.cs), everything is fine:

```
  TimeSpan tmpHSController;

  tmpHSController = start_time.DateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

  Debug.Log(tmpHSController);
```

Again, not exactly sure why this was was happening, but I have resolved/have a workaround for the issue now. If anyone knows why this error was occurring in the first place, please let me know!

Thank you everyone for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in fiddler with the same input and syntax and I'm getting the expected result.  Check how Debug.Log internally handles the TimeSpan object.  Also try to print the values (difference in hour/min/seconds) before you pass it to Debug.Log to check if it reports correct result.

[image]